# How to update the dictionary to get the desired ouput in python?

Tags: python

I need this format but I think I don't know about some more important about dictionaries.I have text file and I want to convert the text file in the format which is given below:

**gameConfiguration.txt**

```
#Rooms
room Hall
room Kitchen
room Storage
room Bedroom
room Bathroom
room Garage
#Doors
door N open Hall Bedroom
door N closed Storage Kitchen
door E locked Hall Storage
door E open Bedroom Kitchen
door N open Bedroom Bathroom
door S open Bedroom Hall
door S open Bathroom Bedroom
door W locked Hall Garage
door W open Kitchen Bedroom
door S closed Kitchen Storage
door W open Storage Hall
door E locked Garage Hall
#Items
item car Garage STATIONARY
item remote Kitchen MOVE
item key Bedroom USE
item key Hall USE
#Start position
start Hall
```

**dictionary**

```
rooms={"Hall":{"name":"Hall","N":{"dir":"Bedroom","status":"open"},"E":{"dir":"Storage","status":"locked"},"W":{"dir":"Garage","status":"locked"},"directions":["N","W","E"],"item":"key"},
           "Bedroom":{"name":"Bedroom","E":{"dir":"Kitchen","status":"open"},"N":{"dir":"Bathroom","status":"open"},"S":{"dir":"Hall","status":"open"},"directions":["E","N","S"],"item":"key","start":1},
           "Storage":{"name":"Storage","N":{"dir":"Kitchen","status":"closed"},"W":{"dir":"Hall","status":"open"},"directions":["N","W"],"start":"Hall"},
           "Garage":{"name":"Garage","E":{"dir":"Hall","status":"locked"},"directions":["E"],"item":"car","start":"Hall"},
           "Kitchen":{"name":"Kitchen","W":{"dir":"Bedroom","status":"open"},"S":{"dir":"Storage","status":"closed"},"directions":["W","S"],"item":"remote","start":"Hall"},
           "Bathroom":{"name":"Bathroom","S":{"dir":"Bedroom","status":"open"},"directions":["S"],"start":"Hall"}}
```

I ignore those lines which started with # and split the lines into words and tried to convert into dictionary what I really want.

**What I Code:**

```
d={}
def dictnPart():
    with open("gameconfiguration.txt",'r') as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            li=line.strip()
            if not li.startswith("#"):
                abc=line.strip().split()
                # print(abc[1])
                if abc[0]=="room":
                    d={abc[1]:{"name":abc[1]}}
                    # print(d)
                if abc[0]=="door":
                    d.update({abc[1]:{"dir":abc[4],"status":abc[2]},"directions":[abc[1]]})
                    # print(d)
                if abc[0]=="item":
                    d.update({"item":abc[1],"directions":abc[2]})
                    print(d)
dictnPart()
```

But the main problem is it's overlapping the recent one and what I'm getting:

```
{'Garage': {'name': 'Garage'}, 'N': {'dir': 'Bathroom', 'status': 'open'}, 'directions': 'Garage', 'E': {'dir': 'Hall', 'status': 'locked'}, 'S': {'dir': 'Storage', 'status': 'closed'}, 'W': {'dir': 'Hall', 'status': 'open'}, 'item': 'car'}
{'Garage': {'name': 'Garage'}, 'N': {'dir': 'Bathroom', 'status': 'open'}, 'directions': 'Kitchen', 'E': {'dir': 'Hall', 'status': 'locked'}, 'S': {'dir': 'Storage', 'status': 'closed'}, 'W': {'dir': 'Hall', 'status': 'open'}, 'item': 'remote'}
{'Garage': {'name': 'Garage'}, 'N': {'dir': 'Bathroom', 'status': 'open'}, 'directions': 'Bedroom', 'E': {'dir': 'Hall', 'status': 'locked'}, 'S': {'dir': 'Storage', 'status': 'closed'}, 'W': {'dir': 'Hall', 'status': 'open'}, 'item': 'key'}
{'Garage': {'name': 'Garage'}, 'N': {'dir': 'Bathroom', 'status': 'open'}, 'directions': 'Hall', 'E': {'dir': 'Hall', 'status': 'locked'}, 'S': {'dir': 'Storage', 'status': 'closed'}, 'W': {'dir': 'Hall', 'status': 'open'}, 'item': 'key'}
```

help me to get the desired ouput.
Please!!

Comment: it will overwrite since you are updating the same key every time,please do refer any tutorials on dict in python

Comment: actually i'm not getting what i want from tutorials thats the reason i have to put this question on stack

Comment: Why do you write `""+abc[4]+""` instead of just `abc[4]`?

Comment: oops sorry I was inserting something else let me update the question

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is? What's the desired output? What are the inputs like? See [ask] and [mcve] for how to ask a question with a high chance of being answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines for `door` and `item` have the room name on them. Use that to access the proper element of the dictionary.

```
d={}
def dictnPart():
    with open("gameconfiguration.txt",'r') as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            li=line.strip()
            if not li.startswith("#"):
                abc=line.strip().split()
                # print(abc[1])
                if abc[0]=="room":
                    d[abc[1]] = {"name":abc[1]}
                    # print(d)
                if abc[0]=="door":
                    roomname = abc[3]
                    d[roomname].update({abc[1]:{"dir":abc[4],"status":abc[2]}})
                    if "directions" in d[roomname]:
                        d[roomname]["directions"].append(abc[1])
                    else:
                        d[roomname]["directions"] = [abc[1]]
                    # print(d)
                if abc[0]=="item":
                    roomname = abc[2]
                    d[roomname].update({"item":abc[1]})
                    if "directions" in d[roomname]:
                        d[roomname]["directions"].append(abc[2])
                    else:
                        d[roomname]["directions"] = [abc[2]]
                    print(d)
```

Comment: Sir not getting the same ouput

Comment: Where are the `1:` and `2:` supposed to come from? Your code uses `{abc[1]: {"name": abc[1]}}` and I copied that, so it uses the room name as the dictionary key, not a number.

Comment: {'Garage': {'name': 'Garage', 'N': {'dir': 'Bathroom', 'status': 'open'}, 'directions': ['N', 'N', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'W', 'S', 'W', 'E', 'Garage'], 'E': {'dir': 'Hall', 'status': 'locked'}, 'S': {'dir': 'Storage', 'status': 'closed'}, 'W': {'dir': 'Hall', 'status': 'open'}, 'item': 'car'}}

Comment: i just use as keys to 1="Hall",2="Bedroom",3="Storage",4="Garage",5="Kitchen",6="Bathroom"

Comment: Maybe you should show what the input file looks like. I assumed that each `room` line was followed by a bunch of `door` and `item` lines for that room.

Comment: I've added a `roomnum` variable that's a number.

Comment: Should i update the question to show you the output?

Comment: rooms={"Hall":{"name":"Hall","N":{"dir":"Bedroom","status":"open"},"E":{"dir":"Storage","status":"locked"},"W":{"dir":"Garage","status":"locked"},"directions":["N","W","E"],"item":"key"},
           "Bedroom":{"name":"Bedroom","E":{"dir":"Kitchen","status":"open"},"N":{"dir":"Bathroom","status":"open"},"S":{"dir":"Hall","status":"open"},"directions":["E","N","S"],"item":"key","start":1},
           "Storage":{"name":"Storage","N":{"dir":"Kitchen","status":"closed"},"W":{"dir":"Hall","status":"open"},"directions":["N","W"],"start":"Hall"},

Comment: "Garage":{"name":"Garage","E":{"dir":"Hall","status":"locked"},"directions":["E"],"item":"car","start":"Hall"},
           "Kitchen":{"name":"Kitchen","W":{"dir":"Bedroom","status":"open"},"S":{"dir":"Storage","status":"closed"},"directions":["W","S"],"item":"remote","start":"Hall"},
           "Bathroom":{"name":"Bathroom","S":{"dir":"Bedroom","status":"open"},"directions":["S"],"start":"Hall"}}

Comment: The question already has the output. Update the question to show the contents of `gameconfiguration.txt`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.This is a huge  help sir thanks a ton!